# Ruby on Rails - concatenate strings on save to database upon user clicking create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, string-concatenation, rails-models

Its late and I probably should sleep on this. Easy one

I have 3 fields in a form which a user fills in. Once they click the create button these records are saved to the database. Simple.

However I want the data from these three fields at the same time to be concatenated together, nothing fancy..and inserted to the database at the same time as the other records. This should reflect back to the user on the show page after they create.

So I need an action to concatenate 3 db columns lets say column names are firstname, surname and DOB. table name PeopleDetails

I have tried building the model using after_create, before_save, built into the model, but nada. suggestions. I think I will come back and revisit this after some sleep

Comment: The `after_create` and `before_save` callbacks are on models, not controllers. Why are you duplicating data in the database like this? For an index? If so, you can just create a unique index on those 3 columns (one index, 3 columns, not 3 indices).

Comment: Yes I am going to use this concatenation as a unique identifier, due to the fact that we have 10 different data sources coming in some with id's some without. So in order to maintain uniqueness with each person we have figured that the easiest way is to concatenate names and date of birth. The likely-hood of a duplicate between the data-sets will be highly improbable.

Comment: @coreyward - sorry I meant model not controller, a little sleep deprived when I wrote.  thanks mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a column (model attribute) called `full_name` than you can combine all together on a model create/save via:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :concatenate_details

  def concatenate_details
     self.full_name = "#{firstname} #{surname} #{dob}"
  end

end
```

Comment: I have had my morning coffee and awake. It works, thanks mate. I did have the model attribute full_name in but had left the inverted commas out. i guess at 3am and one eye closed I missed that. Thanks again